# America the Beautiful pass or single entry - What are the admission fees for CA national parks?

Tags: usa, tickets, national-parks, grand-canyon, yosemite

I'm from Australia and am going to the US for a holiday in November. We are going to Sequoia and doing the Sequoia tour and staying at Sequoia hotel. We are also staying at Yosemite valley lodge and plan to do our own thing. We're also going to the Grand Canyon.

Should I get the *America the Beautiful Annual Pass* or pay upon entry in each national park?

Comment: I'd separate your question about the ATBAB pass into a separate question - multiple questions per post are often frowned upon and likely to get closed on here.

Comment: I tried to keep it simple but also didn't want people asking for more details. I'm pretty much just asking, "should I get ATBAP or just single entry"? - EDIT: How's that?

Comment: I expanded the acronym in the title since I don't think anyone would know what ATBAP stands for by looking at it.  Even Google thinks it's the Amateur Thai Boxing Association of the Philippines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every national park has a different entrance fee policy, but the three you are going to all have the same fees:

[Sequoia and Kings Canyon National Park](https://www.nps.gov/seki/planyourvisit/fees.htm): $30/vehicle for 7 days

[Yosemite National Park](https://www.nps.gov/yose/planyourvisit/fees.htm): <strike>$30</strike> $25/vehicle for 7 days (it reduces for the winter season to $25 starting November 1)

[Grand Canyon National Park](https://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/fees.htm): $30/vehicle for 7 days

That adds up to $85 to visit all three parks. In contrast, the [America the Beautiful Annual Pass](http://store.usgs.gov/pass/annual.html) costs $80, and it works for admission at all three parks, plus many more throughout the country (it does not cover additional fees for things like camping or lodging, nor will it work at state parks). So the pass would allow you to save $5. The downside is that the pass is a fixed cost, so you'd wind up spending a little more if you buy the pass in advance and then don't end up visiting all three parks for any reason.

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: As a related note, ensure you're familiar with the weather and current conditions in these parks, especially Sequoia and Yosemite, if you're visiting in November. Be prepared for cold temperatures and snow, know what highways and roads are closed for the season, and follow weather reports so you're prepared for any storms.

Comment: Actually Yosemite's entrance fee is $25 for November through March.

Comment: @ZachLipton great note +1 why not add that to your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Tom. They don't make that particularly obvious at all, though perhaps they'll update the website on November 1. I don't see any indication Sequoia or Grand Canyon reduces the fee during the off-season, but I'll check their websites in a couple of days to see that it's still the same.